# How to update an object within an array with immutable.js

Tags: immutable.js

I wish to update an objects  in an array using immutable.js

My object looks like this:

```
{
    location: '',
    cars: [
      {id: 1, color: blue},
      { id: 2, color: red}
    ]
};
```

In my code I get for example car id: 2 and change the color { id: 2, color: black}

I now wish to update the car which is at  index 1 .

I tried :

```
const car = { id: 2, color: black}
updateIn([ 'cars'  ], list => list.push(car));
```

This will only add a new car at the end.

Which function in Immutable JS can I use to update car id # 2.

What’s  the correct way to do this with immutable.js

Comment: Can you add some more code for context? For example, what are you calling `updateIn()` on?

Answer (score 1):

```
const car = { id: 2, color: black};
const indexToBeUpdated = 1;
updateIn(["cars", indexToBeUpdated], () => car);
```

whatever the index is, you need to pass it to updateIn methods first argument, which is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Update element in immutable list by condition:

```
const data = fromJS({
    location: '',
    cars: [
      {id: 1, color: blue},
      { id: 2, color: red}
    ]
});

const car = { id: 2, color: black}

const index = data.get(['cars']).findIndex(listItem => {
  // condition here
  return listItem.get('id') === car.id;
});

const new_data = data.setIn(['cars', index], car);
```